# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, valueerror, items

I am tryin to make a field structure but I am having problems while using the for loop with 3 entries in a .items().

```
 dirs = df_vol_erp.groupby(['country', 'primary_volcano_type'])['volcano_name_x'].apply(list)
    #for pais, (tipos, nombres) in dirs.items():
 for pais, tipos, nombres in dirs.items():
        path_pais = os.path.join(new_path, str(pais))
        if not os.path.exists(path_pais):
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(path_pais), exist_ok=True)
        for tipo in tipos:
            path_tipos = os.path.join(path_pais, str(tipo))
            if not os.path.exists(path_tipos):
                os.makedirs(os.path.join(path_tipos), exist_ok=True)
            for nombre in nombres:
                path_nombre = os.path.join(path_tipos, str(nombre))
                if not os.path.exists(path_nombre):
                    os.makedirs(os.path.join(path_nombre), exist_ok=True)
```

I have this code and when run it i get ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1).
I also tried:

for pais, values in dirs.items():
tipos, nombres = values
What can I do ?

Comment: You should use `pathlib` instead of `os.path`. More elegant!

Comment: `for pais, (tipos, nombres) in dirs.items()` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Assign two variables, then in the loop body you can split the second variable into two more variables.

```
for pais, value in dirs.items():
    tipos, nombres = value
```

Comment: Or do `for pais, (tipos, nombres) in dirs.items()`

Comment: @PeterWood He said he tried that... guess he was wrong.

Comment: like this: 
for pais, value in dirs.items():
     tipos, nombres = value
    path_pais = os.path.join(new_path, str(pais))
        if not os.path.exists(path_pais):
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(path_pais), exist_ok=True)
        for tipo, name in value:
            path_tipos = os.path.join(path_pais, str(tipo))
            if not os.path... ?

Comment: I tried but my dirs is list create from a df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['col3'].apply(list)